# What happens to questions with no answer where person asking told the question is not relevant anymore?

Tags: discussion

This is my first post in meta. Check this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91820/sharing-application-built-by-flex

A person asking is not expecting any answer any longer and has briefly described "the answer" in a comment. What shall we do/what happens to this question?

I've read that there are roughly 2K questions with no accepted answers and it is a pity if those are like this one.

Comment: Welcome to Meta!!

Answer (score 12):

Some options I can think of to reduce such situations:

- On good/common questions:

  1. The first thing you may try is to leave a comment to the OP encouraging him or her to answer their own question as best as it can be.
  2. If none reply is given, you can go ahead an post an answer based on what is written in the comments and additional info.
- On off-topic/poor threads:

  1. If the question is not relevant or not so good in quality, choose one option to flag it and put on hold.
  2. If the question does not fit in close reasons but still has poor content, just downvote it. If it gets more than 3 downvotes it will go away.

Comment: Thank you, Andre, good to know!

Comment: +1 OP encouraging him or her to answer their own question