# Are extension specific questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

["Error in Parcel Selection" in SaeX in ArcGIS 9.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231076) has been put on hold as off-topic:

> This **problem cannot or can no longer be reproduced**. Changes to the
>   system or to the asker's circumstances may have rendered the question
>   obsolete, or the question does not include a procedure to enable
>   potential answerers to reproduce the same symptoms. Such questions are
>   off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers, but editing
>   them to include more details can lead to re-opening.

This problem is specific to arcgis extension SaeX, and there are many users of SaeX. the question is related to arcgis and to reproduce it, SaeX is needed. This question will be useful to many SaeX users.

Should such extension specific questions be allowed in this site?

Comment: @AndreSilva I think the key part of the Close Reason here is "Such questions are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers" which I think actually fits in this situation.

Comment: @Midavalo, that sentence is important indeed. I provided an answer sharing my interpretation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, questions relating to ArcGIS plugins are on-topic at GIS SE and the question has been reopened. In the question you reference, it is best to provide information about the plugin such as a hyperlink or a short description. Additionally, providing information about your workflow will help future readers.

Answer (score -1):

About your specific question, I believe [Aaron answers](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4507/are-extension-specific-questions-allowed/4508#4508) it well.

---

About the close reason which was used to put the question "on hold":

It is used for questions when OP says the question is solved without saying why. [Or possibly when OP provides an "answer" as a comment and abandon the question](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3585/what-happens-to-questions-with-no-answer-where-person-asking-told-the-question-i/3586#3586).

Also, it is used when questions are "unlikely to help future readers" in the following cases:

- Obsolete questions due to changes in the system or in the asker's circumstances;
- Questions which do not include a procedure to enable potential answerers to reproduce the same symptoms.

Your closed question does not fit in any of above scenarios so, it should not have been closed with this specific close-reason.

Comment: @PolyGeo, the point is about using the correct close reasons; and votes when close reasons do not apply.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I think OP provided an answer to a problem/error other users may have faced. It is information for our repository; if it is good or bad info, votes will help to tell. I don't think 'on-topic ness' of GIS subjects have to do with their popularity. Therefore, I could not see how that off-topic close reason fit into that question, but people may disagree.